# CardView size issue on View Recycle

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, cardview

I have created a recyclerview adapter class, with an item layout which contains a cardview inside which there are some textviews and imageviews. The problem I am facing is that when the views are recycled, my cardview size changes and it hides the content of another cardview.

I think the issue is because I have different card heights for each item. So when an item is recycled, it takes the height of another card which is different. How to fix this? Please help..

Video link of the problem: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nlgq-eQ-rhRNadOyzg4FwjVzrIk88Ve8/view?usp=sharing

open_up_list_view.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/openUpCardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimen_16x"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_16x"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_4x"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/dimen_8x">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/openUpRelativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/dimen_8x"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ProgressBar
                        android:id="@+id/openUpAuthorImageProgress"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                        android:id="@+id/openUpAuthorImage"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_48x"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_48x"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen_4x"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_4x"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_4x"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_4x"

                        app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"
                        app:civ_border_width="2dp" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/openUpAuthorName"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/cardview_default_radius"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_8x"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_8x"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_8x"
                        android:text="loading.."
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_16x"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/openUpDate"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/openUpAuthorName"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_8x"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_12x" />
                </RelativeLayout>


            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/openUpTextView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:autoLink="web"
                android:padding="@dimen/dimen_4x"
                android:textAlignment="textStart"
                android:textColor="@color/cardview_dark_background"
                android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_16x" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/openUpImageProgress"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                <com.github.chrisbanes.photoview.PhotoView
                    android:id="@+id/openUpImageView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen_8x"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_4x"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_4x"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_8x"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark" />


            </RelativeLayout>


            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0.5dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="false"></View>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/openUpLikeIcon"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_32x"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_24x"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen_4x"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/thumb_off"
                    android:button="@null"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:stateListAnimator="@animator/scale"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/image" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/openUpLikeTextView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_8x"

                    android:text="loading.."
                    android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_16x" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/openUpCommentIcon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/fab_margin"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_8x"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/comment_icon" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/openUpCommentTextView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_8x"

                    android:text="loading.."
                    android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_16x" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/openUpDeleteText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_4x"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_8x"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Delete"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_16x" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/commentSeparatorView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1.5dp"

                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="false"></View>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/commentSeparatorText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/dimen_8x"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Comments"
                android:textColor="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_focused" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/commentsLL"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_4x"
                android:background="@null"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/commentsRecyclerView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">


                </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:hint="Add a comment..">

                        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                            android:id="@+id/commentEditText"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                        android:id="@+id/commentPostButton"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                        android:text="POST"
                        android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

EDIT: RecyclerView layout

fragment_open_up.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.bittentech.localvariable.fragments.OpenUpFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/openUpEmptyView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="All caught up!!" />
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/openUpSwipeRefresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">



    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/openUpRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"/>




</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Is this list_item xml of the recyclerView?

Comment: It is the layout of a single item in the RecyclerView

Comment: And all your data is using the same item, right?

Comment: Yes I am using same layout for all the items

Comment: Great. Did you try implementing the same without `<ScrollView>` in the item xml? You don't need a scrollview there as `RecyclerView` itself is scrollable.

Comment: I tried, no help either..

Comment: Ok, write this `@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {    
    return position;
}` in your adapter class

Comment: I did, what does it do?

Comment: Does it work now as expected?

Comment: No, still the same problem.